# Как программно менять содержимое dimens.xml

Tags: android

У меня есть файл dimens.xml, в котором собраны все используемые размерности. Мне нужно менять некоторые из них, чтобы дать пользователю настраивать текст, отступ и тд. как программно изменять этот файл?

Comment: Вы так все и пытаетесь освоить выпуск квадратных велосипедов? Искрени рекомендую вам заканчивать и почитать уже нормальную книжку по разработке и архитектуре приложений Android. Узнаете много нового и главное перестаните тратить время на тупиковые решения. Смысл файла `dimens.xml` в том, что он хранит константные значения размерностей интерфейса, которые НЕ БУДУТ изменяться. Все динамическое по интерфейсу хранится в преференсах (или БД в некоторых случаях)

Comment: @pavlofff, да я изначально и хотел все в Preferences хранить, но подумал, а вдруг и так можно?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Это невозможно*. Ресурсы приложения заносятся в R класс на этапе компиляции и изменить их можно лишь скомпилировав приложение заново.

Вам придётся для всех настроек заводить значения в SharedPreferences. И в коде эти значения присваивать в нужные места. И при смене к-л значений каждый элемент в коде же перерисовывать. Ну или пересоздать активити.

---

*Ну, на самом деле вы можете программно декомпилировать своё приложение, изменить нужные данные в нужных файлах, снова его собрать, установить и запустить. Но вы ж не будете всерьёз эту возможность рассматривать, не правда ли? =)

Comment: А как можно декомпилировать?) И можно ли декомпилировать часть приложения, а потом ее "вставить" в установленное? P.S. Спрашиваю чисто из интереса.

Comment: 1. ХЗ. Вроде какие-то проги для этого есть... В AS, вроде, можно декомпилировать отдельные классы из jar-ов. 2. Насколько я знаю - нет. Но наверняка есть способ не стоящий времени на его освоение. Ресурсы задуманы статическими и пытаться их менять - категорически неправильно.

Comment: Ну почему же? Так можно создать приложение, которое само будет себя обновлять, без ведома пользователя, не требую установки и тд.!

Comment: @bukashka101, насколько я понимаю, разобрать апк и его собрать можно втиую. А вот установить апк - уже без юзера почти никак не выйдет.

Comment: Я знаю! А вот модифицировать уже существующее...

Comment: @bukashka101, ну, тут я вам ничего не скажу, т.к. на эту тему ничего не знаю) Попробуйте вопрос такой задать - может кто и ответит чего)